# Garmin Ant Agent USB sticks is not working on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, garmin

I have a garmin gps training watch that connect with Ant agent (http://www8.garmin.com/support/download_details.jsp?id=3741) but in my new install of windows 8 the USB drivers are not working anymore I get a device problem, I downloaded the latest drivers but it did not work. I also try to install it manualy but no more luck. I made a request to Garmin support but if some has a solution until they fix it, let me know!

Comment: Try opening `Device Manager` and using generic drivers for your devices.

Comment: I already did, it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's now working, just installed all the software and last update from everything and it works.